# Iterating through a map of lists in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to set up a generic, yet customisable template.

So using modules, I want to iterate over a map containing lists, something like:

```
module "instance"
{
  ...

  ip_by_subnets = {
    subnet1 = [ip1,ip2]
    subnet2 = [ip3]
    subnet3 = []
    subnet4 = [ip4,ip5,ip6,...]
    }
  ...
}
```

Where

```
subnet# = a subnet cidr block
ip#     = private IP address
```

For each subnet I need to run through and create an instance for each private ip.

psuedo code would essentially do this:

```
foreach subnet# in ip_by_subnets
    foreach ip# in list
       create an instance resource
```

But I can't figure out the code to put in the resource template.
Made a few bad attempts at it e.g.

```
subnet_id = "${element(var.ip_by_subnets[count.index])}"
```

but that's not gonna work right.
I also thought about using a `count` in the module, but then I'd have to move the elb to its own module. Which I can do, but I wana try this way first

Anyone know how to do this? 
Any suggestions for other methods (e.g. different data structure are appreciated)

Comment: Are you absolutely set on that data structure or can it be different?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR It can be different, I just like the way that one looks. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems this was not (easily) feasable prior to terraform 0.12 release.

The 0.12 release includes `For` expressions amongst many other improvemnets

```
{for s in var.list : s => upper(s)}
{
 "a" = "A" 
 "b" = "B" 
 "c" = "C"
}
```

Not tested, but imagine it would work somethnig like:

```
{for l in var.map : for s in var.list : s => upper(s)}
    {
     "a" = "A" 
     "b" = "B" 
     "c" = "C"
    }
```